# Django makemigrations Segmentation fault

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django rest api in Docker-compose on a raspberry pi 3B with 1gb of RAM. The postgresql database and the nodejs frontend run without any problem. But for the django backend the output of docker-compose up is a segmentation fault:

```
backend | + python3 manage.py makemigrations restapi
backend | No changes detected in app 'restapi'
backend | scripts/start_server.sh: line 29:    13 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 manage.py makemigrations restapi
```

line 29 in start_server.sh refers to:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations restapi
```

Any ideas where the segfault is coming from or how I could find out what's the problem? Might this be a memory issue? I configured a 8GB swap alongside the 1GB RAM. Would this prevent python to run out of memory? The exact same configuration runs fine on my PC with 8GB RAM so I suppose there isn't a problem with my django models.

Edit:
if i skip the makemigrations and jump to migrate I also get a segfault:

```
backend |   Applying restapi.0001_initial... OK                 
backend |   Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK                
backend | scripts/start_server.sh: line 31:    13 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 manage.py migrate
```

Edit2:

I tried to run it on a Pi 4b with 8GB RAM and i still get the same error. I successfully ran it on two other machines that also have 8GB RAM (PC and Laptop). Hence I assume that RAM is not the issue.
The only thing the two pis had in common was the 60GB sd card and ubuntu 20.4 server. I did a fresh setup for each of them.

Edit3:
Not a solution but a temporary workaround: the commands "python3 manage.py makemigration", "python3 manage.py migrate" etc. each lead to a segfault but it seems like they are still executed before crashing. Thus I can rerun docker and each time comment out the last command until all commands are applied. Then django runs without any error and the database is complete. However this leaves me puzzled as I don't understand the possible reason for the segfault.

Comment: The slow SD card of a Raspberry Pi is not suitable for swap memory. Deactivate the swap and and monitor the RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you don't have enough memory, try a machine with more than 1GB memory

Comment: it works on a machine with 8gb memory. but isn't the swap supposed to compensate for the lack of memory?

Comment: There is only one thing that can replace RAM: more RAM

Comment: I tried to run it on a Pi 4b with 8GB RAM and i still get the same error. I successfully ran it on two other machines that also have 8GB RAM (PC and Laptop). Hence I assume that RAM is not the issue. Any other ideas?